# Is there a way to filter dimension in holoviews Sankey diagram

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, holoviews

I am trying to show migration from locations in a Sankey diagram in Holoviews, but I can't find a way to add a dropdown-type filter. I am not allowed to list a higher number of key dimensions than what I am plotting, which I expected to work as I get dropdown menu in other HoloViews elements as it automatically groups my data by all the key dimensions I did *not* assign to the element.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts

hv.extension('bokeh')

df = pd.DataFrame({'from': ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"],
                   'to': ["d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "d"],
                   'number': [10, 2, 1, 8, 2, 2],
                   'year': [2018, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017]})
df

from    to  number  year
0   a   d   10  2018
1   b   d   2   2018
2   c   e   1   2018
3   a   e   8   2017
4   b   e   2   2017
5   c   d   2   2017
```

Now to Holoviews adding the year column to kdims as I want the dropdown to filter by year:

```
kdims = ["from", "to", "year"]
vdims = ["number"]

sankey = hv.Sankey(df, kdims=kdims, vdims=vdims)
sankey.opts(label_position='left', edge_color='to', node_padding=30, node_color='number', cmap='tab20')
```

returning:

```
ValueError: kdims: list length must be between 2 and 2 (inclusive)
```

Without the third key dimension the Sankey diagram work as expected, but then there is no interactive filter:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want a HoloMap of Sankey Elements; see http://holoviews.org/reference/containers/bokeh/HoloMap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's 2 ways of solving your problem:

**1) Turn your dataframe into a holoviews dataset and turn that into a Sankey plot:**
Since 'year' is in the code below the 3rd key dimension, it will be used as the dimension for the slider. The first 2 variables ('from' and 'to') will be used as the key dims for the Sankey plot.

```
hv_ds = hv.Dataset(
    data=df, 
    kdims=['from', 'to', 'year'], 
    vdims=['number'],
)

hv_ds.to(hv.Sankey)
```

**2) Or, create a dictionary of Sankey plots per year and put those into a holomap:**

```
sankey_dict = {
    year: hv.Sankey(df[df.year == year]) 
    for year in df.year.unique()
}

holo = hv.HoloMap(sankey_dict, kdims='year')
```

**Both solutions create a holomap:**
http://holoviews.org/reference/containers/bokeh/HoloMap.html

**Resulting plot + slider:**
[image: holomap sankey slider]

I've tested this on:
hvplot 0.5.2
holoviews 1.12.5 and holoviews 1.13
jupyterlab 1.2.4

Comment: Halfway there, I get the slider, but changing the slider does not change the Sankey plot (no interactivity) when exporting as html with hv.save(....

Comment: @NRVA if I do as follows, i do get a interactive html: hv.save(plot, 'sankey.html', fmt='html') Does this also work for you?

Comment: No, without fmt I get slider with no interactivity. with fmt I don't get slider at all.

Comment: But I do get interactivity :) Which version of holoviews are you using? You can install the newest version with: pip install git+https://github.com/pyviz/holoviews.git

Comment: Holoviews 1.12.7. super weird

Comment: Please try to install the latest version 1.13 using commandline: pip install git+github.com/pyviz/holoviews.git

Comment: I will mark this as solved, even if I have yet to verify the solution (I ran into trouble with anaconda trying to update to 1.13). But thats a whole other problem. Thanks for the solution:)

Comment: Thanks :) I use conda to create an environment, but then use pip to do all my package installs